# Aruba Wireless Controller 200 and AP70 manual

Tags: wifi, access-point, controller, aruba

I have an Aruba wireless system that is currently in use but there is no documentation from the previous person in charge. I have no manuals or login information for the wireless controllers and APs.

I checked the Aruba website and you need to register to access the support information but registration isn't instant and takes several days. I've waited for quite a while now and have tried googling and checking the Aruba forums but have found no indication of a manual.

What I really need is the ability to reset the controller and APs so I can access the device with the default username and password. There is no reset button on this device so I have no idea how you go about resetting the controller and APs.

Hm it seems I can't create a new tag as a new user. If possible can someone add an "Aruba" tag?

Answer (score 1):

This should reset your device to factory default. From my reading, you'll still need to reapply the licenses.

Boot with the serial connection. In the command prompt try the following:

```
User: password
Password: forgetme!
> enable
Password: enable
> configure terminal
> mgmt-user admin root
Now enter new admin password:
> write memory
> exit
> exit
> exit
```

Comment: This will only reset the admin password and change it. Not factory default the device or cause you to need to re-apply the licenses.

Answer (score 1):

If you have console access with the admin account and the enable password you can reset an aruba controller with

```
write erase
```

If you need to reset the passwords you will need to connect to the serial port and do:

```
User: password 
Password: forgetme!
(aruba)> enable
Password: enable 
(aruba)# configure terminal
Enter Configuration commands, one per line. End with CNTL/Z
(aruba) (config)# mgmt-user admin root 
Password: <new admin password>
Re-Type password: <new admin password>
(aruba) (config)# exit
(aruba)# exit
(aruba)> exit

User: admin
Password: <new admin password>
(aruba)> enable
Password: enable 
(aruba)# configure terminal
Enter Configuration commands, one per line. End with CNTL/Z
(aruba) (config)# enable secret 
Password: <new enable password>
Re-Type password: <new enable password>
(aruba) (config)# write memory
(aruba) (config)# exit
(aruba)# exit
(aruba)> exit
```

When applying a new image remember to follow the release note document for the specific release.

Answer (score 0):

See this Aruba forum post: http://airheads.arubanetworks.com/vBulletin/showthread.php?t=977